# How can I do it in linear time for every year?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, asymptotic-complexity

The question is as follows:
Every year I get N grades (not discrete numbers 0-100),

A. I need to find the maximal grade for the year.

B. In the end of the N year, I need to return the N highest grades from all the N^2 grades from all the N years.

T(i) is the runtime of the algorithm in year i.

I need to propose an algorithm/data structure which will do A & B in 
MAX(T(1), T(2), ..., T(N)) = O(N). (Linear work in every year)

A solution in O(NlogN) is the lowest I got by maintaining a maximum heap of the N maximal grades from every year and maximal heap for every year, and delete min and insert the next in line from which year we deleted.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You have no ordering of any sort? I don't see how you can avoid looking at  least once at all the N^2 grades then ... I don't even see your O(N log N) working.

Comment: @JeanLogeart every year the algorithm receives N grades, and must process them in O(N).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an array with N*2 positions.

1. In the first year, fill the first N positions.
2. In the second year, fill the remaining N positions.
3. Run the [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm (with median of medians) to partition the array between the N largest and the N lowest in O(N).
4. Repeat from 2 until year N.

Comment: What is the argument I give the deterministic select algorithm ? What will happen if I have duplicated grades ? Many duplicated grades ...

Comment: In second thought, I will lose the non-duplicated grades constraint, since it's the N largest grades and I don't see a solution without duplicates that will not destroy the linear time complexity. Thank you for the solution !